# swap between grid and list fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

The main section of my screen layout shows a set of items. The use can choose if a grid or a list should be shown. Therefore I implemented two fragements (for list and grid) that are then shown inside the placeholder (main section of the main layout).

But now I wonder how to reuse the fragements in order to have the last scrolling position etc. If I remember the fragment in a private field instead of re-creating it, then the view remains empty.

Any idea?

```
public void onShowGrid(View view) {

    // how to re-use instead of re-create
    fragmentGrid = new PreviewGridFragment();

    this.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.preview_fragment, fragmentGrid)
            .addToBackStack(null).commit();
}

public void onShowList(View view) {

    // how to re-use instead of re-create
    fragmentList = new PreviewListFragment();

    this.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.preview_fragment, fragmentList)
            .addToBackStack(null).commit();
}
```

[image: Dynamic Fragments]

Comment: Instead using the fragment use the view.setvisibility it's quiet easy to manage

Comment: True, but this means using a lot of memory. But keeping the fragments would be the same memory consumption.

Comment: I want to use the same fragments within other parts of my app. Therefore fragments are the better choice than views.

Comment: ok then save the position of the item and when you come back move to that position

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not a good idea to save your fragments in private fields because it consumes memory and you do not need to do it, better idea is creating static field in each fragment and save the last position in that then when you create your new fragment scroll to that position.